# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have a WCF service, that requires client authentication with certificate.

I have a simple console application that consumes this WCF.

I have 2 client certificates, with the first one the console applications works perfect and with the second one, it returns this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

As I see in the IIS logs, is a 403.7.

Both certificates are installed **in the same store** and both have the same permissions in **Manage Private Keys** for the user that executes de console application.

Both certificates have:

- **Private key**
- **Key Usage**: Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (f0)
- **Enhanced Key Usage**: Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
- Are **valid** and have the **same certification path**

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I activate SCHANNEL logging, when I user the certificate that fails, on the Event Viewer we see this error:

[image: **enter image description here**]

**SOLVED**

The problem was that we was getting the certificate using:

X509FindType.FindBySubjectName

And with the subject that we are using, there are at least another 3 certificates that contains that subject.

Then the certificate we are getting is not the correct, we change the code to use

X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName
or
X509FindType.FindByThumbprint

And now gets the correct client certificate and works.

Comment: My only guess is that your request cannot authenticate through the WCF service because it might be hosted inside an aspnet application maybe?

Comment: If the certificates are both valid, have the same certification path and are configured the same, then the issue may likely be with the WCF configuration. Perhaps you could post the relevant sections of the app.config file for review (<endpointBehaviors><behavior><clientCredentials><clientCertificate findValue="")

Comment: I have a customBinding: <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false"
         authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered"
         unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="true"/>

Comment: I think the client still needs to identify the certificate to use by specifying the:
(<endpointBehaviors><behavior><clientCredentials><clientCertificate findValue="")

Comment: I assign the client certificate in code,    X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection x509Certificate2Collection = x509Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, text, true);
    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Certificate2Collection[0];

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server certificate validation mode.
[image]
For example, when we use the **CertificationValidationMode=Custom**, we could specify the custom X509validator class which implements

```
System.IdentityModel.Selectors.X509CertificateValidator
```

It could have custom validation when processing the client certificate.
If **CertificateionValidationMode=ChainTrust**, you must ensure that the client is stored in the right store area, and in the same chain with the server certificate.
What is the server certificate validation mode?
Feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: We have on the server a custom behavior that gets the certificate and checks, but the behavior with this certificate never is executed. The service returns the error before the behavior gets executed.